# How to migrate Vuex Method-Style Access to Pinia setup store

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

> Pinia. In Setup Stores: ref()s become state properties, computed()s become getters, function()s become actions.

> Vuex. Method-Style Access. You can also pass arguments to getters by returning a function. This is particularly useful when you want to query an array in the store:

```
getters: {
  // ...
  getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
  }
}


store.getters.getTodoById(2) // -> { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
```

Not work

```
const getItemsByType = computed((element: string) => {
  return data.value[element] ? data.value[element] : []
})
```

That is like action but with return and also not help

```
  const getItemsByType = (element: string) => {
    return computed((element: string) => {
      return data.value[element] ? data.value[element] : []
    })
  }
```

That work, but that is an action and not getter(if consider that a getter is only with computed()) and is not cached

```
const getItemsByType = (element: string) => {
  return data.value[element] ? data.value[element] : []
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computed cannot have an argument.

From Vuex docs:

> Note that getters accessed via methods will run each time you call them, and the result is not cached.

So the Method-Style Access in Vuex is just a getter returning function. Equivalent in Pinia is to use plain function (last example)

```js
const getItemsByType = (element: string) => {
  return data.value[element] ? data.value[element] : []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintainer @posva answer https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1569#discussioncomment-3429724

It's actually the same as Vuex

Options stores:

```
defineStore('store', {
  getters: {
    foo: state => (param) => state.bar + param
  }
})
```

Setup Stores:

```
const getItemsByType = computed(() => 
  (element: string) => data.value[element] ? data.value[element] : []
)
```

Comment: Second example is pointless - wrapping function into `computed` has no benefits. Also [confirmed by posva](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1569#discussioncomment-3436650)